# Algebraic proof of finiteness of von Dyck groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The [von Dyck groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_group#Von_Dyck_groups) are quotients of the free group on two generators defined as $$D(l, m, n) = \langle  x, y | x^l = y^m = (xy)^n = 1\rangle$$ where $l, m, n \geq 2$. These groups are the symmetries of a particular triangulation of a (possibly non-Euclidean) surface with triangles of angles $\pi/l, \pi/m, \pi/n$, and  are finite if and only if $$\frac{1}{l} + \frac{1}{m} + \frac{1}{n} > 1,$$ in which case the surface is a sphere, which obviously has a finite set of symmetries. (The possible values of $(l, m, n)$ are $(2, 2, n)$ where $n \geq 2$ and $(2, 3, n$) where $3 \leq n \leq 5$, plus permutations.)

There was a question yesterday from someone who asked if $D(2, 3, 5)$ was finite and couldn't find a proof working from the group presentation alone. Is there an argument distinguishing the finite from the infinite von Dyck groups that works *purely* algebraically, rather than appealing to geometric properties of the group action? I suspect that these arguments would be difficult to find because the finite and infinite groups have superficially similar presentations, but I can't shake the feeling that there should be one.

Comment: If I may borrow from the subtitle of Stanley Kubrick's movie [Dr. Strangelove](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0057012), I can only suggest that one learn to stop worrying and love the Poincare Polygon Theorem.

Comment: In a more serious vein, the geometric methods of proof are important and useful. The geometric tools behind the von Dyck groups and other examples arising from the hyperbolic, euclidean, and spherical geometry have given rise to entire sub-branches of group theory, including [small cancellation theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_cancellation_theory), Gromov's theory of [hyperbolic groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_cancellation_theory), and [geometric group theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_group_theory).

Comment: Even [combinatorial group theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_group_theory) itself is infected with those geometric ideas.

Comment: The finiteness proof for the dihedral groups is easy, and the other examples ((2,3,3), (2,3,4), (2,3,5)) can be proved finite by hand using coset enumeration,  but the geometric argument is more general and uniform.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the Coxeter group 
$$G=G(\ell,m,n)=\langle u,v,w\mid u^2=v^2=w^2=(uv)^\ell=(uw)^m=(vw)^n=1\rangle.$$

Consider the homomorphism onto $\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}$ mapping each generator to $1(\neq 0)$. Just using that $u,v,w$ square to $1$, its kernel $K$ is generated by $uv$, $uw$, $vw$.

Now let's change the presentation changing $(v,w)$ with $(x,y)$, for $x=vu$, $y=uw$ (so $K$ is generated by $(x,y,xy)$. It gives
$$G=\langle u,x,y\mid u^2=(xu)^2=(uy)^2=x^\ell=y^m=(xy)^n=1\rangle,$$
rewritten
$$G=\langle u,x,y\mid u^2=1,\quad x^\ell=y^m=(xy)^n=1,\quad uxu^{-1}=x^{-1},uyu^{-1}=y^{-1}\rangle.$$
We identify the presentation of a semidirect product $\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}\ltimes D(\ell,m,n)$. In other words, the index 2 subgroup $K$ of $G$ is isomorphic (through $(x,y)\mapsto (x,y)$) to $D(\ell,m,n)$.

This is not a proof of finiteness, but reduces the finiteness of $D(\ell,m,n)$ to that of the above Coxeter group $G(\ell,m,n)$, and this is (now!(*)) a much more documented result.

(*) I guess von Dyck studied these groups in the 1880s, much before Coxeter groups were introduced.

Comment: This answer would benefit if somebody can suggest some reference of algebraic/combinatorial flavor for the classification of finite Coxeter groups.